# Git Push given Local and Remote Branch Name

Tags: git

Given a local branch name

```
"refs/heads/foo" (or "foo")
```

and a remote branch name

```
 "refs/remotes/origin/bar" (or "origin/bar")
```

is there a way to feed the names directly to `git-push/fetch/pull` without manually parsing the branch names, extracting the remote name and producing a valid refspec like

```
origin refs/heads/foo:refs/heads/bar
```

?

The reason is the ref names get fed into a script and the values are 2 refs (or their shorthands).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  This is ... unfortunate, because manually obtaining the *first* one is easy:

```
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name foo
```

does the trick, but manually obtaining the *second* one is not.  The result of a full symbolic lookup of `origin/bar` is `refs/remotes/origin/bar` (and of course the result of a similar lookup of `refs/remotes/origin/bar` is also `refs/remotes/origin/bar`), but there's no simple way to map that back to the branch name as seen on `origin`.

For instance, suppose that the result of `git config --get-all remotes.origin.fetch` is `+refs/heads/sneaky:refs/remotes/origin/bar`.  Then the branch name as seen on `origin` is not `refs/heads/bar`, but rather `refs/heads/sneaky`.  Now, hardly anyone ever does things like this, but it *can* be done, and it's not immediately clear to me what result you'd like, if someone did do that.

You could *assume* that the fetch refspec is the standard one (`+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`), or you could check and refuse to proceed if not.

Note that `git push` itself doesn't try to undo this kind of craziness in every (or maybe even any?) case: there are a dizzying array of push options, both in the command itself and in the Git configuration (e.g., `remote.origin.push`).

You could just ignore all this potential weirdness, and assume that once you have a string beginning with `refs/remotes/origin/`, that the remainder is the name to pass to the Git over on `origin` via your refspec.  That, at least, has the virtue of simplicity: just use `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name` twice and then do the matching.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the answer. It just seems to me git should have a command for that - there are commands for much more exotic use cases. Thanks!

Comment: I think so too: perhaps `git rev-parse` should have a flag that says to do the reverse mapping, or something like that.